# Are there any LaTeX packages for multicolumn typesetting besides multicol?

Tags: packages, two-column, multicol, licensing

I'm going to need two-column layout (more advanced than LaTeX's `\twocolumn` - I'll need changing the number of columns without starting a new page or column balancing); however, due to the nature of the (commercial) project, I do not want to use `multicol` because of its license (and yes, I read it carefully, and in my opinion the "moral obligation" to pay a strictly positive fee lies on me, and I would very much prefer to avoid this.).  Is there any other (free) LaTeX package which would enable multicolumn typesetting?

(I *am* considering using ConTeXt, too, but since there are multiple authors who supply manuscripts in LaTeX, and I have a tested template (read: document class) which I only need to modify, this would be rather a drastic step.)

Comment: By the sound of it the "moral obligation" indeed puts it on you. But a) the size of the fee is also on you and depends on how valuable you consider multicol is for your project. I have seen everything from a nice postcard together with the book for which it was used up to substancial fees. And of course many who ignored it. But b) what is wrong in giving something to the community back? You could pay, whatever you feel like to the LaTeX3 fund at TUG.

Comment: Frank: I totally agree with *all* your points.  However, in this case (a) the *just* fee would probably be substantial and (b) there is nothing wrong, and I indeed feel indebted to the TeX community; however, I am barely in black recently, and very much prefer giving back in the form of answering here from time to time, posting on my TeX blog or giving lectures about TeX.

And (c) just theoretically - apart from my case - I'm quite interested in the problem of the possibility of typesetting in a few columns in LaTeX with a *completely* free tool.

Comment: One clarification: there's *nothing wrong* with me if anyone licenses his/her package as a non-completely-free tool; still, having a huge, *free* suite like LaTeX and not being able to do quite a quite *basic* typographical task seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: I'm sure I can't count the minutes of my life that I spent on developing and enhancing a free LaTeX. The multicol "moral obligation" is a historical accident that just happened, see the discussion in the [LPPL paper](http://www.latex-project.org/papers/tb100mittbach-lppl-history.pdf). But for this reason it is as it is and I do not regret it. As for (a) this honors you but of course you are free to tune it done as much as you like down to null in fact.

Comment: concerning (c): you say you need twocolumn without _starting a new page or column balancing_. but you can't have that both: either you balance or you need to start a new page at least if the first column already got filled. So what is it you are looking after?

Comment: @mbork: look at the ctan catalogue, and you'll see that ctan (and the distributions) take the licence to be free.  *nobody* (in their right mind) would expect you to pay more than you can afford, from your pocket; but you said you wanted the package for a commercial enterprise -- if so, perhaps there will be a pay-back time; if so, you could make a donation _then_.

Comment: Concerning (c): what about starting two columns in the middle of page 1 and balancing them on page 2?  (AFAIR, `multicol` does this - am I wrong?)  anon: you are right, that is why I take such a solution into consideration, but still, I'd like to know the answer.

Comment: @mbork ok, so you are interested in column balancing. I found the "or" in your question a bit of a strange wording. Yes, multicol does that and ltxgrid too (as far as I remember, with its own set of limitations and problems). That's about  the only two options that I know of other than going manually.

Comment: @mbork Please consider closing this question, by accepting one of the answers or by providing your own and accepting it.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: the time I'll need this answer is going to come quickly (a few weeks at most), and then I'll check the `ltxgrid` package and close this question.

Comment: @mbork That's fine, otherwise is shown as unanswered and the mods are trying to reduce them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An option would be to use the [`ltxgrid`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxgrid) package, developed by Arthur Ogawa as part of the `revtex` distribution that is used to typeset papers for the American Physics Society ([aps.org](http://aps.org)) journals.

The `ltxgrid` package was commissioned by the American Physical Society
and is distributed under the terms of the `LaTeX Project Public License`,
the same license under which all the portions of LaTeX itself is distributed.
See [lppl](http://ctan.tug.org/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt) for the license details.

As concerning the "moral obligation" of commercial use of `multicol` I think the arguments you put forward, are contradictory and your concerns unfounded. You say in the comments:

> ...the just fee would probably be substantial and (b) there is nothing
>   wrong, and I indeed feel indebted to the TeX community; however, I am
>   barely in black recently...

The moral obligation is to thank the author of the package in any way you can afford, when the commercial venture is on the way and to make a contribution later on as you may deem fit once it starts generating substantial income and as you say the just fee becomes  substantial. Same is morally true for any of the free source software, either being TeX related or otherwise. Just don't talk to a lawyer listen to your inner self. As I mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37352/963, the LaTeX project can do with some funding.

Many corporate beneficiaries of both publicly funded research as well as open source software have indigestion when it comes to giving something back to the community. You can find an interesting discussion at the HN thread [Research Bought, Then Paid For: Open Access to Science Under Attack](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3451510). I find this disheartening and a poor trait of the human nature.

Answer (score 5):

Can you use the `minipage` environment instead?

If you have multiple minipages defined immediately after each other, they will appear next to each other (as long as the sum of the widths does not exceed \textwidth). For example, to produce a two-column layout, you could use the following:

```
% first column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
This is the first column.\\

This is still in the first column.
\end{minipage}

%second column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
This is the second column.
\end{minipage}
```

The other thing you could do is put the text in a two column table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth} }

column one blah blab blah

&

column two blah blab blah

\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I'll have to do a lot of manual tuning, so it is rather a "last resort" type of thing.