# How to use ltxgrid to switch between one and two columns

Tags: output-routine, ltxgrid

After reading answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40920/are-there-any-latex-packages-for-multicolumn-typesetting-besides-multicol), I decided to give `ltxgrid` a try.  A simple experiment showed that using `\twocolumngrid` and `\onecolumngrid` do their job; however, the vertical space between one- and two-column fragments is way too small (see MWE below).  From skimming through the `ltxgrid` manual I deduce that I am using it in a wrong way.  Now what is the *proper* way?  (For simplicity one may assume that there won't be any pages with both one and two columns, though this assumption may need to be dropped at some point, so more general answers are welcome.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltxgrid}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\twocolumngrid
\lipsum[3-4]
\onecolumngrid
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add some space like `\addvspace{2\baselineskip}`. The reason why you thinking you are using it wrongly is that the author recommends that you leave these decisions to the class as options or semantically named macros.

For example here is the definition of `titlepage`.

```
\renewenvironment{titlepage}{%
 \let\wastwocol@sw\twocolumn@sw
 \onecolumngrid
 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
 \c@page\z@% article sets this to one not zero???
 }{%
 \wastwocol@sw{\twocolumngrid}{\newpage}%
 }%
```

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{ltxgrid}
%\usepackage{ltxutil}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\columnsep1.5em
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\addvspace{2\baselineskip}
\twocolumngrid
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering\rule{3cm}{3cm}\end{figure}
\lipsum*[1-2]
\begin{figure}[t]\centering\rule{3cm}{3cm}\end{figure}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

Note the floats.

Comment: @mbork Nice thing with this package which I am also trying to get  to know it, is that the floats work! If you use it eventually post an image or two under your question.