# Customizing ltxgrid

Tags: ltxgrid

Continuing my [my fight with ltxgrid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47196/how-to-use-ltxgrid-to-switch-between-one-and-two-columns), I'd like to know how to customize it; in particular, I'd like to know how to change the horizontal distance between columns.

Comment: I believe it's the usual `\columnsep` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As egreg noted you use `\columnsep`. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{ltxgrid}
\usepackage{ltxutil}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\columnsep1.5em
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\addvspace{2\baselineskip}
\twocolumngrid
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering\rule{3cm}{3cm}\end{figure}
\lipsum*[1-2]
\end{document}
```