# balanced longtables, multicol and page breaks

Tags: longtable, multicol

For a long time, I have been looking for a nice way to have balanced tables inside a multicol environment. Especially, I would like to have automatically balancing multicol-tables inside a `table` float. While I always thought that this is merely impossible with LaTeX in its current state, I have recently discovered an extraordinary useful answer on this topic:

[Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex)

However, when I apply this technique to the case I'm investigating, I encounter a somewhat odd behaviour. Please consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Lorem ipsum}
\date{\today}
\author{\LaTeX}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newenvironment{multicolslongtable}[1]{
  \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
  \col@number\@ne
  \begin{longtable}{#1}
}{
  \end{longtable}
  \unskip
  \unpenalty
  \unpenalty\egroup
  \unvbox\ltmcbox
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{multicolslongtable}{c l}
1 &Lorem\tabularnewline
2 &ipsum\tabularnewline
3 &dolor\tabularnewline
4 &si\tabularnewline
5 &amet\tabularnewline
6 &consectetuer\tabularnewline
7 &adipiscing\tabularnewline
8 &elit\tabularnewline
\end{multicolslongtable}
\end{multicols}
\caption{Words of the first sentence by index.}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]
[image: page2]

Please note that:

- There is a large gap in the right column of the first page.
- The text of both columns overruns the boundary on the first page, but not on the subsequent page(s)

I would be glad for any suggestions on how to fix this and improve my `multicolslongtable` environment.

Comment: _Just as reference for other people:_ “Because of the requirement to auto-balance material and the use of columns with different width there are some restrictions with respect to floats: **it is only possible to use full-width floats** as the notion of a general column width doesn't exist and the balancing would make float placements very complicated.” – [Frank Mittelbach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/) in [What are the main advantages to using the multicol package over the twocolumn documentclass option?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103270)

Comment: @Speravir yes but that quote isn't the issue: the OP was using a full width float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, but I did not immediately realize and wanted to give a hint for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I blame Frank:-)

That is, I think the problem is unrelated to `longtable`, but rather that it is dangerous to nest `multicols` environments.

If you use the inner `multicols` to hold the longtable *before* starting the outer one, and save the result in a box to add to the float. it works better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\title{Lorem ipsum}
\date{\today}
\author{\LaTeX}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newsavebox\xxbox
\newenvironment{multicolslongtable}[1]{
  \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
  \col@number\@ne
  \begin{longtable}{#1}
}{
  \end{longtable}
  \unskip
  \unpenalty
  \unpenalty\egroup
  \unvbox\ltmcbox
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\savebox\xxbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{multicolslongtable}{c l}
1 &Lorem\tabularnewline
2 &ipsum\tabularnewline
3 &dolor\tabularnewline
4 &si\tabularnewline
5 &amet\tabularnewline
6 &consectetuer\tabularnewline
7 &adipiscing\tabularnewline
8 &elit\tabularnewline
\end{multicolslongtable}
\end{multicols}
\captionof{table}{Words of the first sentence by index.}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table*}[t]
\usebox\xxbox
\end{table*}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These two boxes could also be merged, or not?

Comment: @Speravir they could here but best not really, the inner one is local use just within the environment, to wrap longtable. the extra one declared here needs 1 box _per table_ or at least one box for all tables in a given multicol as it globally needs to hold the precomputed float body.