# environment to balance a table in a multicol

Tags: tables, longtable, multicol

## environment to balance a table in a multicol

I'd like an environment that balances a table in a multicol environment.

By this I mean I'd like to have potentially long tabular-like data
that automatically breaks to another column of a roughly equal number of rows.

like so, automatically breaking after row 3, for a 2 column tabular, into a 2 column multicol
(artist's rendition)

```
lipsum lipsum lipsum lipsum lipsum

    row1 col2        row4 col2
    row2 col2        row5 col2
    row3 col2

lipsum lipsum lipsum lipsum lipsum
```

Additionally, I was looking to use `xparse` and a `multicol` to do this,
in order to pass the number of columns to use through the custom environment down to multicols.

Additionally, I was looking to use the book class and `showframe` package.

I've tried two solutions:

### solution A, long table

This answer produces the correct output but not when I wrap it in an environment:

[Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex%7D)

I've tried two fixes:

#### solution A, fix 1: replace the `\vbox{` and `}` with `\bgroup`and `\egroup`

Attempt no. 1 results in misaligned columns, and these errors:

- Undefined control sequence. \begin{myenvironment}
- Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.
- Undefined control sequence. \end{myenvironment}
- misaligned columns
- `@numberne` appears in the columns

[image: solution 1, attempt 1]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
}
{
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
    \egroup\unvbox\ltmcbox
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

This works great!
\shortlipsum
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \shortlipsum
    \medskip
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
        \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
        \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
            \tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
        \end{longtable}
        \unskip
        \unpenalty
        \unpenalty
    }
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
    \medskip
    \shortlipsum
\end{multicols}

\shortlipsum
\par

This does not work!
\begin{myenvironment}
\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

#### solution A, fix 2: replace the `\vbox{` and `}` with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`

Attempt no. 2 results in a loss of output past the first `\shortlipsum` and:

- Missing { inserted. \begin{myenvironment}
- Undefined control sequence. \begin{myenvironment}
- Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.
- Undefined control sequence. \end{myenvironment}
- Missing } inserted. \end{myenvironment}

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\begingroup
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
}
{
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
    \endgroup\unvbox\ltmcbox
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

This works great!
\shortlipsum
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \shortlipsum
    \medskip
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
        \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
        \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
            \tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
        \end{longtable}
        \unskip
        \unpenalty
        \unpenalty
    }
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
    \medskip
    \shortlipsum
\end{multicols}

\shortlipsum
\par

This does not work!
\begin{myenvironment}
\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

### solution B, pseudo-nested longtable w/ savebox

This answer also produces what I want, but I couldn't get it to align with the text.

[balanced longtables, multicol and page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks)

I've tried:

#### solution B, fix 1: wrap the commands in an env and remove the table, and that works great!

[image]

However...

That works great until I add the `showframe` package and I get:

- Missing } inserted. \begin{myenvironment}[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnZWT.png)
- Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup{myenvironment}
- added space under the longtable

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newsavebox\xxbox
\newenvironment{multicolslongtable}[1]{
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
    \col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}
{
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty\egroup
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \savebox\xxbox\bgroup
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{multicolslongtable}{| l | l | l |}
}
{
    \end{multicolslongtable}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \egroup
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
        \usebox\xxbox
    \end{multicols}
}


\begin{document}

\shortlipsum

\begin{myenvironment}[2]
\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
\end{myenvironment}

\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`? It does the same but without breaking your code.

Comment: @AboAmmar perfect! thank you!
I wasn't aware of that option.
I'll clean up the code and post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to use the `showframe` option from `geometry` package instead of the `showframe` package.

Thank you [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar)!

The code below shows an environment that balances tabular data
using a longtable in a multicol (with showframe),
by combining the following answers, `xparse`, and minor refactoring:

- [balanced longtables, multicol and page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks)
- [one-column multicol environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment)

[image]

```
% environment to balance a table in a multicol

\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}


% helpers for the test
\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}
\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}


% box for a multi column long table
% SEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newsavebox\xxbox
\newenvironment{multicolslongtable}[1]{
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
    \col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}
{
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty\egroup
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
}
\makeatother


% environment to accept table input and produce multicol
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \savebox\xxbox\bgroup
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{multicolslongtable}{| l | l | l |}
}
{
    \end{multicolslongtable}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \egroup
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
        \centering
        \usebox\xxbox
    \end{multicols}
}


% patch multicols to allow for one column
% SEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment
\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
    \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
    \fi
}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

\section{one column}
\shortlipsum
\begin{myenvironment}[1]
\tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\section{two column}
\shortlipsum
\begin{myenvironment}
    \tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\section{three column}
\shortlipsum
\begin{myenvironment}[3]
    \tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document example can't be compiled, it throw the same error as you reported in question. BTW, `showframe` doesn't interact with page content. Cause of your error is something else.