# environment fails on import of certain packages (longtable / multicol)

Tags: tables, longtable, multicol

I have en environment that fails if I add any of these calls to the preamble:

- `\usepackage{pgfornament}`
- `\usepackage{tikzsymbols}`
- `\usepackage{xcolor}`
- `\usepackage{tikz}`
- `\hypersetup{colorlinks={true}}`

It results in:

- `Missing } inserted. \begin{myenvironment}`
- `Extra }. or forgotten \endgroup. \end{myenvironment}`
- weird spacing

**Question** Is there a way to make the environments compatible with the calls above?

**Question** Would you give me some background on this error and how to approach it?

---

### Example

The environment is meant to balance tabular data in multiple columns.

See,

- [environment to balance a table in a multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555318/environment-to-balance-a-table-in-a-multicol/555453#555453)

And,

- [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex)
- [balanced longtables, multicol and page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks)
- [one-column multicol environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment)

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[%
showframe,%
twoside,%
top=0.75in,%
bottom=0.75in,%
marginparsep=3ex,%
marginparwidth=0.8in,%
inner=0.75in,%
outer=1.25in,%
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    papersize={6in,4in}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}    % must be the last package
\hypersetup{%
    pdfauthor            = {MyAuthor},
    pdftitle             = {MyTitle},
    pdfsubject           = {MySubject},
    pdfkeywords          = {MyKeyword},
    linkcolor            = {magenta},
    urlcolor             = {blue},
    citecolor            = {cyan},
    filecolor            = {black},
%   colorlinks           = {true},  % causes Missing } inserted in myenvironment
}

% I was hoping to use these...
%\usepackage{pgfornament}        % causes Missing } inserted in myenvironment
%\usepackage{tikzsymbols}        % causes Missing } inserted in myenvironment

% I Don't really need these but they also break it
%\usepackage{xcolor}             % causes Missing } inserted in myenvironment
%\usepackage{tikz}               % causes Missing } inserted in myenvironment


% helpers for the test
\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}
\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}


% box for a multi column long table
% SEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newsavebox\xxbox
\newenvironment{multicolslongtable}[1]{
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
    \col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}
{
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
    \egroup
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
}
\makeatother


% environment to accept table input and produce multicol
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \savebox\xxbox
    \bgroup
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{multicolslongtable}{| l | l | l |}
}
{
    \end{multicolslongtable}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \egroup
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
        \centering
        \usebox\xxbox
    \end{multicols}
}


% patch multicols to allow for one column
% SEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment
\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
    \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
    \fi
}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

\section{without `pgfornament` etc.}
\shortlipsum
\begin{myenvironment}
    \tablines
\end{myenvironment}
\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

---

### attempt 1: \bgroup --> \begingroup

Swapping out `\bgroup` --> `\begingroup` and `\egroup` --> `\endgroup`, results in a loss of output (`Extra }`, improper `\prevdepth` and many more)

---

### attempt 2: try [balanced longtables, multicol and page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks) again

This potential solution is compatible with the packages but I still can't refactor it into an environment.

**Question** Is there a way to refactor this into an environment properly?

It works when I copy / paste it (the first two tabulars) but I'd like to avoid that.

The environment produces

- `Undefined control sequence \begin{myenvironment}`
- `Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.`
- misaligned rows
- `@numberne` added where a row should be

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[%
showframe,%
twoside,%
top=0.75in,%
bottom=0.75in,%
marginparsep=3ex,%
marginparwidth=0.8in,%
inner=0.75in,%
outer=1.25in,%
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    papersize={6in,7in}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}    % must be the last package
\hypersetup{%
    pdfauthor            = {MyAuthor},
    pdftitle             = {MyTitle},
    pdfsubject           = {MySubject},
    pdfkeywords          = {MyKeyword},
    linkcolor            = {magenta},
    urlcolor             = {blue},
    citecolor            = {cyan},
    filecolor            = {black},
    colorlinks           = {true},  % no longer causes Missing } inserted
}

% no longer causes Missing } inserted
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

% for testing
\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}
\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}


% patch multicols to allow for one column
% SEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment
\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
    \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
    \fi
}
{%
    \ifnum#1=1
    \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
    \fi
}

% temporary box for multicols
\newsavebox\ltmcbox

% copy the working commands below into an environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
}
{
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
    \egroup
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
    \end{multicols}
}


\begin{document}

\shortlipsum

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
        \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
        \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
            \tablines\tablines
        \end{longtable}
        \unskip
        \unpenalty
        \unpenalty
    }
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}

\shortlipsum

\begin{multicols}{1}
    \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
        \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
        \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
            \tablines\tablines
        \end{longtable}
        \unskip
        \unpenalty
        \unpenalty
    }
    \unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}

\shortlipsum

\begin{myenvironment}
    \tablines\tablines
\end{myenvironment}

\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

---

### other considerations

#### `supertabular`

this answer [multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration) tricks a `supertabular` into working in a `multicol` but I would like the tabular-like data to be on one page, in between text

#### `tabbing`

might work but

- my tests so far don't balance well per row or center it horizontally
- I was looking to have formatting per colum like in a `tabular`
- I was looking for the column widths to be calculated by LaTeX

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[%
showframe,%
twoside,%
top=0.5in,%
bottom=0.5in,%
marginparsep=3ex,%
marginparwidth=0.8in,%
inner=0.5in,%
outer=1.25in,%
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    papersize={6in,3in}
}

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}

\def\entry{9000 \> Watt \> Power\\}

\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvironment}{O{2}}
{
\centering
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabbing}
\hskip4em \= \hskip4em \= \hskip16em \kill
}
{
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols}
\par
}


\begin{document}

\shortlipsum

\begin{myenvironment}
\entry
\entry
\entry
\entry
\entry
\entry
\entry
\entry
\end{myenvironment}

\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

#### `list`

A list might work

- but I wanted more than two columns
- my experiments so far don't align it well

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[%
showframe,%
twoside,%
top=0.5in,%
bottom=0.5in,%
marginparsep=3ex,%
marginparwidth=0.8in,%
inner=0.5in,%
outer=1.25in,%
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    papersize={6in,3in}
}

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\par}


\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    
    \shortlipsum
    
    
    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{
        \item[#1] #2
    }
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \centering
        \begin{description}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
            \entry{1}{2}
        \end{description}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \shortlipsum
    
\end{document}
```