# What is the license for the multicol package?

Tags: multicol, licensing

The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/multicol.pdf) for `multicol` mentions on the first page:

> Note: This package is released under terms which affect its use in commercial applications. Please see the details at the
>   top of the source file.

However, [the archive](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) says it's distributed under [the normal TeX license](https://ctan.org/license/lppl1.3c), which doesn't seem to put any conditions on its use (only on redistribution and modification).

Which is correct? What should I keep in mind if I want to use `multicol` in e.g. a book?

Comment: Somewhat related, see also comments here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40920

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the line you quote says, the details are in the source file. It is distributed in LPPL with an additional clause:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
%
% This file is part of the Standard LaTeX `Tools Bundle'.
% -------------------------------------------------------
%
% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%    https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% The list of all files belonging to the LaTeX `Tools Bundle' is
% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse    This is a METACOMMENT
%
%% Package `multicol' to use with LaTeX2e
%% Copyright 1989-2018 Frank Mittelbach
%%
%%  In addition to the terms of LPPL any distributed version
%%  (unchanged or modified) of multicol has to keep the statement
%%  about the moral obligation for using multicol. In case of major
%%  changes where this would not be appropriate the author of the
%%  changed version should contact the copyright holder.
%%
%%
%%  Moral obligation for using multicol:
%%  ------------------------------------
%%
%%  Users of multicol who wish to include or use multicol or a modified
%%  version in a proprietary and commercially market product are asked
%%  under certain conditions (see below) for the payment of a license
%%  fee.  The size of this fee is to be determined, in each instance,
%%  by the commercial user, depending on his/her judgment of the value of
%%  multicol for his/her product.
%%
%%
%%  The conditions for this are as follows:
%%
%%   The producer of a proprietary and commercially market product
%%   that involves typesetting using multicol is asked to determine
%%   the value of a license fee for using multicol if
%%
%%   - the product is a document and the producer has decided to
%%     include multicol to typeset (parts of) the document or has
%%     directed the author of the document to include multicol (for
%%     example, by providing a class file to be used by the author)
%%
%%   - the product is a LaTeX class or package that includes multicol
%%
%%
%%   There is no moral obligation in case
%%
%%   - the product is a document but producer has not directed
%%     the author to include multicol (in that case the moral obligation
%%     lies with the author of the document)
%%
%%   - the product does not involve typesetting, e.g., consists, for
%%     example, of distributing multicol and its documentation.
%%
%%   - the product is not proprietary, i.e., is made available as free
%%     software itself (which doesn't prohibit its commercial marketing)
%%
%%   - multicol is used for non-commercial purposes
%%
%%
%% Determining a license fee might result in a license fee of zero
%% (i.e., no payment) in case a producer has determined that the use
%% of multicol has no enhancing effect on the product. This is a
%% plausible scenario, i.e., in the above two cases the producer is
%% only asked to evaluate the value of multicol for the product
%% not for the payment of a license fee per se (which might or might
%% not follow from this evaluation).
%%
%% The license fee, if any, can be payed either to the LaTeX3 fund
%% (see ltx3info.txt in the base LaTeX distribution) or to the author of
%% the program who can be contacted at
%%
%%     Frank.Mittelbach@latex-project.org
%%
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll accept as soon as the timer allows.

Comment: there is some history behind the license and the moral oblication of multicols, see article at https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/lppl/