# Customizing Gonzalo Medina's Award Winning Entry

Tags: fonts

I am trying to do few modifications to Gonzalo Medina(GM)'s [award winning contest entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday/35093#35093).   I want to change the fonts GM used in the header box.  I achieved partial success by changing following lines in GM's gridleno.sty

```
\color{headtitle}\Huge\lecturenotename \\[6pt]
      \fontfamily{cmr}\fontsize{17pt}{20pt}\selectfont\scshape\@topic \\[6pt]
      {\normalsize\rmfamily\scshape\@professor}%
```

to

```
 \color{headtitle}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{16pt}{20pt}\selectfont\scshape\lecturenotename \\[6pt]
      \fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{24pt}{20pt}\selectfont\scshape\@topic \\[6pt]
      {\normalsize\rmfamily\scshape\@professor}%
```

See the attached figure. [I made few other changes, of course.]

[image]

In a comment to GM's entry, @dochar mentioned the following [site](http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html).

It says

> If the font can be made generally available on your computer (e.g., to
>   other word processing programs), you can use XeTeX or LuaTeX to access
>   it directly, without any TeX-specific installation at all.

How can I do that?  That is, what do I have to change in GM's above lines to use, say, Braggadocio regular, a font available in my computer?

Comment: You need the package `fontspec` which makes all the fonts available.

Comment: @Marco Daniel: It is in GM's contest.tex file.  Perhaps I should move it to gridleno.sty?

Comment: In fact it is important to load `fontspec`. If you load the package you can create a new font face `\newfontface`. An example is given in the documentation of `fontspec` (page 9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minimal answer to the question.

Add the following to gridleno.sty (preferably, after the 20th line of gridleno.sty).

```
\@ifpackageloaded{fontspec}{}{\RequirePackage{fontspec}}
```

Change line 88 from

```
\color{headtitle}\Huge\lecturenotename \\[6pt]
```

to

```
\color{headtitle}\fontspec{Braggadocio}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont\scshape\lecturenotename \\[6pt]
```

Make sure you compile Gonzalo Medina's contest.tex using XeLaTeX.

The following is the heading box of the output.
[image]