# Block comments with *% and %*

Tags: macros, environments, comments

I know the package `comment` which allows to use :

```
\begin{comment}
Lines
to
comment
\end{comment}
```

This is not very friendly to use. I would like to have the following possibility:

```
*%
Lines
to
comment
%*
```

This is similar to the multiline version of comment in JavaScript, C or C++.

This kind of syntax is very useful because I could then use...

### Comment

```
*%
Lines
to
comment
%*
```

### No comment

```
%*%
Lines
to
comment
%*
```

Is there a way to use `*%` and `%*` instead of `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` respectively?

Comment: It is possible if you are using luaTeX. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35017/323

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible without LuaTeX, but not in a robust way. I used `~%` and `%~` instead of `*` because making `*` active would break commands which expect `*` to be of category code other (e.g., `\section*{...}` would not work anymore).

```
\begingroup
    \catcode `\@ = 11
    \catcode `\~ = 13
    \catcode `\% = 12
    \protected\long\gdef\cmt@remove#1%~{\endgroup}
    \ifdefined~
        \global\let\cmt@old~
    \else
        \global\let\cmt@old\relax
    \fi
    \protected\gdef~{\begingroup\catcode`%=12
        \futurelet\next\cmt@}
    \protected\gdef\cmt@
      {\ifx%\next
           \expandafter\cmt@remove
       \else
           \endgroup\expandafter\cmt@old
       \fi}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 6):

In ConTeXt MkIV, you can do this with the normal comment environment (which is called hiding). The environment stop mark need not be on a line of its own. So, you can use:

```
\starttext
Normal
\starthiding                                                                                                                              
  Hidden
%\stophiding
\stoptext
```

If you comment the line starting with `\starthiding`, the hidden content will be shown.

But if you want to include and exclude environments, it is better to define a new comment environment and use `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` to change its behavior.