# Is there an easy way to comment out a whole block?

Tags: formatting, comments, source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-line (block) comments in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex)

Is it possible to comment out a whole block in LaTeX source?

For example, like in `Java`:

```
// This is an in-line comment.

/*
   This
   is a
   block
   comment.
 */
```

Is there anything like that in TeX?

```
% This is an in-line comment.

% But how to avoid commenting out 
% every
% single
% line?
```

For example with using something like that `/% ... %/` ?

Comment: Can be related: [Block comments with *% and %*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/block-comments-with-and).

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex

Comment: Okay sorry, I don't know what I did wrong while searching for this, but I just saw this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex - Please close as exact duplicate.