# How to create attendance sheets?

Tags: tables, formatting, lists

Is there a package for creating sheets you fill out by handwriting?

Like for example attendance sheets, a list of key borrowers, a sign-off sheet for dangerous stuff etc.

Basically some sort of table with a caption, multiple columns and helper-lines to separate different entries. Rows large enough for Joe-handwriter. Perhaps a counter in the first column and some paragraph of text above/below.

Comment: first I thought "this is a simple table" what's the big deal? but then I thought "how can I make just the right number of lines to fill up a single page?" now I'd like to find the answer!

Comment: Have a look at mbork's answer on [Contest: show off your skillz in TeX and friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my feble attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline &&&&\rule{0cm}{1cm}}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}

a paragraph of text
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
Name & Item & Pickup & Return& Signature
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 15}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip

a final paragraph of text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are ways to change the background so that it alternates in the rows, and it would be nice to automatically find out how many lines to put...but that's currently beyond my powers.

Comment: would you give a example of subcolumns?