# How to set width of column's with their name in table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

I get a solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42186/128718 where he gave a solution to create attendance sheet in LaTeX. His solution is good.

But,he put column's width and title in separate line. When I have many columns and need to change the column's width again and again to adjust it with expected looks, I have to search the `p{width}` for that column that is boring and time consuming.

So, if there is a way that allow to put the width alongside the column's title it is easy to change any column's width.(e.g. `column{|Name}{width=2cm}`)

You can give any solution to create attendance sheet/other table with the expected feature.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that highlights your usage?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\makebox` to combine the width and title in one step. It does not check to make sure the title will fit in the space requested.  Once could also use `\parbox`.

I started playing around with the loop to add lines, discovered it was harder than I thought, then decided it wasn't worth the effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2.5}% vertical spacing in multiples of \strut
\def\aline{&&&&\\\hline}% number of & = number of columns-1
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\makebox[2cm][l]{Name}& 
\makebox[2cm][l]{Item}& 
\makebox[2cm][l]{Pickup}& 
\makebox[2cm][l]{Return}& 
\makebox[2cm][l]{Signature}\\\hline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\aline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to eliminate the left and right cell margins using `@{}` in the column definition:

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|}
```

Then for your header row you can overlap the header names (using `\rlap`) with a horizontal space of the width you desire:

```
\rlap{ Name}\hspace{2cm} & \rlap{ Item}\hspace{3cm} & \rlap{ Pickup}\hspace{2cm} & \rlap{ Return}\hspace{2cm} & \rlap{ Signature}\hspace{3cm}
```

---

Another possibility is to insert comments into your column definitions. You could define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\xx}[1]{}
```

that does nothing. So `\xx{stuff}` will basically just turn `stuff` into a comment. Your code would look like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}\xx{name}|p{3cm}\xx{item}|p{2cm}\xx{pickup}|p{2cm}\xx{return}|p{3cm}\xx{sign}|}
```