# LaTeX table's vertical line not shown

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
%\usepackage{a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm}{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline &&&&\rule{0cm}{.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|p{.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}}
\hline
Name& Room& L/11& D/11& B/12& L/12& D/12& B/13& L/13& D/13& B/14& L/1& Deposit& Cost& Extra& Due
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 15}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I modified this code from [How to create attendance sheets?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42182/how-to-create-attendance-sheets) For this code the output looks like -

[image]

Expected output looks like -

[image]
The column after`B/12` has no vertical bar. Why?

Comment: The problem is in your `\aline` macro. You only have 4 `&` symbols (giving 5 columns). You need 15 of them.

Comment: @SandyG yes, you are right. But, why the vertical bar is ovelapped the title?

Comment: Your columns are too narrow. Simply change `p{0.5cm}` to `p{0.7cm}`

Comment: Or make the font smaller (e.g., scriptsize) in the title entries.

Comment: @bmv But, see there is space before the title.

Comment: @alhelal: There is a padding in the table called `tabcolsep`. You can change it: `\setlength\tabcolsep{<whatever length>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{.4cm}}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.75cm}|p{1cm}|p{.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
Name& Room&L&D&B&L&D&B&L&D&B&L&Deposit&Cost&Extra
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 48}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

output

[image]