# Split a scanned photo across multiple pages (with a predifined splitting point)

Tags: graphics

I am a relative (La)TeX newbie! I want to split an A4 scanned image across two pages! Is there a  package to achieve this or is it possible to do this manually so that to be able to define the exact  splitting point?

Comment: Thank you Yiannis for your reply!  My photos are normal A4 pages from an old text book. So lets say that I want to place some scanned page at some line of the current A4 text  and downwards. So it is very likely to have to properly split the photo (let say 1/3 of A4 from the top where there is space and no text). So I would like a command(with the splitting point as a parameter) to perfectly split the scanned page.

Comment: Best to experiment with a real image and text page can you post a scan or see if you can find a link to google books for the textbook? I am not sure if understand you correctly. The image is A4, so you will only display 2/3 of the picture? How about the cropped part?

Comment: I 'll try to post one. But fist let me make an example for clarify myself. I write some comments about history then I insert some  A4 scanned page from an old book, then I make some new comments and then again I insert a new A4 scanned page and put some new comments...e.t.c. So I need a package and/or a command mixing text and scanned pages in a natural way (i.e without loss of information when there is a need to split some  scanned pages)

Answer (score 19):

You haven't provided any specific details as to the image and page layout so  I will describe a general technique that I use here. You can either split the image into two to achieve a centerfold or you can hide a portion of it, as is shown in the two images below, which I had on my hardisk from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35162/963).

[image][image]

Here is the MWE. You can use `\hspace` to move images left or right. If you have a single image, you let it overflow on the right (it will not show if it goes past the page) and on the next page, you insert it at the same position, but now with an `\hspace*{-\textwidth}` to pull it left. This way you do not need to slice the image before hand. If you care to explain in more detail as to the layout you want to achieve, I will extend the example and code. You should also have a look at LaTeX3 [xcoffins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=xcoffins).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=5mm,left=5mm,right=5mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\textbf{\LARGE FUN IN AMERICA}
\vspace*{0.8cm}
\begin{figure}[h] % can be left out
\hskip-0.5cm\includegraphics[width=1.055\textwidth]{./graphics/funinamerica}\\[-17pt]

\hfill{\tiny\bf Fun in America from a page spread in Life Magazine circa 1940's. \quad}\hfill\hfill\\

\par\bigskip
\centerline{\LARGE\bf AMERICANS ARE HAVING FUN}
\end{figure} % can be left out but do adjust spacing as needed
\unskip

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\linewidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}

\clearpage
\vspace*{-2pt}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
\hskip-1cm\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./graphics/funinamerica01}\\[3pt]
\hskip-1.5cm\begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
\footnotesize \textbf{AIRING} in Central Park during the 1860s was favorite Sunday diversion for rich New Yorkers who, between 4 and 5 o'clock, turned out in fashionable carriages for trot around the 10 miles of park roads.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}\hspace{20pt}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\hskip-0.5cm\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./graphics/pologrounds}\\
\footnotesize\textbf{PROFESSIONAL BASEBALL} was well launched  by 1880s and teams like Giants were publicised by huge posters used grounds of New York Polo Club (above) unil 1889, then moved further uptown.
\end{minipage}
\vskip5pt
\hskip25pt\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./graphics/amusementpark}\\[-17pt]
\captionof*{figure}{\footnotesize \textbf{AMUSEMENT PARK}, called Elysioan Fields, in Hoboken, NJ. sported a hand-operatedpleasure railway with tiny carriages for 6c visitors could ride the railway, row boats and swing in a big gondola.}
\end{minipage}
\vskip5pt
\hskip-0.5cm\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./graphics/tippling}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}\footnotesize \textbf{TIPPLING} is varying degrees was pastine from coast to frontier. New York rendevous was Gem Saloon where gentlemen in top hats should shake hands with mayor and swill down oysters and flips.\end{minipage}\vspace{-1cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Simpler images and code is possible, as shown below.

[image][image]

```
\minipage{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{./graphics/firesidecomfort}
\endminipage

\hspace*{-1\textwidth}\minipage[t]{\textwidth}\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{./graphics/firesidecomfort}
\endminipage
```

Since we size the image on the `\textheight` the image overflows to the right. Then the only thing we need to do on the following page is to pull it by `\textwidth`. Amazingly simple and powerful.