# Handwritten parchment. Quill style

Tags: fonts, color

- I want to know a few fonts that look like this:
  [image]
- I want to know what are the colors that were used to write with quill or some colors that could be used in the document.
- I would like to split the [image of an open book](http://www.alfredom.com/art/free-6.htm) in two parts and use one for even pages and another for odd ones.
- It would be nice to have a little of transparency in some random and small parts of the text.

  [image]

Here is the latex code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{calligra,xcolor,wallpaper}
\usepackage[driver=pdflatex]{hand}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{BC0000}% blue 0D1126
\title{Handwritten document}
\author{Arturo}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\CenterWallPaper{}{background.png}
  \calligra\Large
  {\color{red}\maketitle}
  \begin{handpar}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, feugiat ad metus vestibulum at
    eget. Condimentum est dictumst, quis cras congue et turpis, ornare
    lacinia hendrerit platea in. Nulla est proin pellentesque hendrerit
    nulla vitae.
  \end{handpar}
  \color{MidnightBlue}
\begin{handpar}
  Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacustincidunt ul-trices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hachabitasse plateadictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementumfermentumwisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odioplacerat quam,ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit ametnisl.Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
\end{handpar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand the last part of your question but I'm having some trouble with the first two. You seem to be using `calligra` already: is this not suitable for some reason? If not, what's the problem? I have no idea what you mean about the colour. Either this question is way off-topic for this site (being a historical matter concerning ink composition during a particular period) or it seems you have already answered it (since you use colours in your example).

Comment: For the part of the question I understand, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45104/split-a-scanned-photo-across-multiple-pages-with-a-predifined-splitting-point seems to be a duplicate? Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214568/spread-image-pages-in-chapter-opener?lq=1? Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right?

Comment: I want a more readable font than calligra, I suppose the colour question is off-topic, the duplicate questions don't use the wallpaper package to write over the image.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this in LaTeX?   I know nothing of fontspec with xelatex, but these are recommended when it comes to fancy font import.

Comment: I don't mind if it is in LaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLateX

Comment: So the `wallpaper` package is required? You won't consider any other solutions? Why not? [My answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214605/) writes over a background image which is split across 2 pages. Could you explain why you are particularly set on using the `wallpaper` package?

Comment: Do note, too, that the site operates a one question per question policy. If you have several related questions, you can link them, but they are still separate questions. I don't understand what you want in terms of the transparency, either. That is an addition to your original question, I think. Why not just leave some space? That is, how does transparent text differ from no text? Re. splitting one of those 'open' images: there is no neat vertical you can draw to divide the image into the 2 pages. So you can divide the image, but it won't correspond to the original page break.

Comment: The transparency would be like if the quill is drying. That image split is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.