# Is it possible to create a hyperlink with any name and linking to any place?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

Is it possible to create hyperlinks in LaTeX that will show up as arbitrarily defined strings in the output (PDF/DVI)?

For example, something like to appear in the output file:

Text text text text text text  text text text text.

Here,  would direct the reader to a position in the document that would be chosen arbitrarily by the user, e.g. to the end of the 45th paragragh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `hypertarget` and `hyperlink` commands from the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) pacakge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

In the beginning \hyperlink{linkanchorname}{Text text text text text text text text text text.}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\hypertarget{linkanchorname}{Here's our anchor!}
\end{document}
```

The example I've demonstrated above is very simplistic, but you can do *a lot* with this idea. For example, you can link questions and answers to and from each other which has been demonstrated in a lot of questions- [Adding another answer hyperlinked to the question itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/adding-another-answer-hyperlinked-to-the-question-itself) is one such example.

Comment: Or `\hyperref[<label>]{text}` and `\phantomsection\label{<label>}`.

Comment: Nice! It's times like these that remind you why you use (La)TeX.