# Incrementing counters with subsubsection instead of subsection

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, counters

I have previously tried to make a document with questions and answers.
In a previous question I was shown a great way to do this, using the `answer` package in combination with `hyperref`.

[Adding another answer hyperlinked to the question itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/adding-another-answer-hyperlinked-to-the-question-itself)

The problem is that the document has grown quite large, counting over 100 pages. 
I need to reset the counters for the answers and questions at the `subsubsection`
instead of at the 'subsection'. I tried changing the counters in the answer provided, but alas either the document failed to compile, or nothing changed at all.

Here is a minimal working example with the counters reset at the subsection level
http://spot.pcc.edu/~chughes/buzzard/

I know this must seem like a trivial question, but for a novice like me the code was quite hard to interpret.

A even more minimal example, the backhypperrefs fail here. Also I am not able to reproduce the error where it fails to distinguish between the subsubsections

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}                            
\usepackage{enumitem}                       
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0mm}

% very useful during de-bugging!
%\usepackage[left]{showlabels}
%\showlabels{hypertarget}
%\showlabels{hyperlink}

% solutions files
% short solutions
\Opensolutionfile{shortsolutions}
\Newassociation{shortsolution}{shortSoln}{shortsolutions}
% long solutions
\Opensolutionfile{longsolutions}
\Newassociation{longsolution}{longSoln}{longsolutions}

% new environment that sets up hypertargets both in the question
% section, and in the answer section
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{3}
\newcounter{question}[subsubsection]
\newenvironment{question}[1]%
    {%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    %  hyperlink to solution
         \hypertarget{question:{\thequestion}}{}%
         \Writetofile{shortsolutions}{\protect\hypertarget{shortsoln:\thequestion}{}}%
         \Writetofile{longsolutions}{\protect\hypertarget{longsoln:\thequestion}{}}%
         \begin{myenum}[label=\bfseries\protect\hyperlink{shortsoln:\thequestion}{\thequestion},ref=\thequestion]
         \item%
            \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
            \hyperlink{longsoln:\thequestion}{#1}%
        }%
        {%
        \end{myenum}}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}

\subsubsection{Set I}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $-\frac{2}{3}(4-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                In order to do this, we must first make a substitution\ldots
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int(2x-1)^{50}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{1}{102}(2x-1)^{51}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                A very long solution| much longer than the shorter solution
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt[n]{x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{n}{n+1}x^{\frac{1+n}{n}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                Even longer!
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\subsubsection{Set II}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{n}{n+1}x^{\frac{1+n}{n}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                Even longer!
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $-\frac{2}{3}(4-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                In order to do this, we must first make a substitution\ldots
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int(2x)^{50}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{1}{102}(2x-1)^{51}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                A very long solution| much longer than the shorter solution
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\clearpage

\section{Questions}

\subsubsection{Set I}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $-\frac{2}{3}(4-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                In order to do this, we must first make a substitution\ldots
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int(2x-1)^{50}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{1}{102}(2x-1)^{51}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                A very long solution| much longer than the shorter solution
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt[n]{x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{n}{n+1}x^{\frac{1+n}{n}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                Even longer!
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\subsubsection{Set II}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{n}{n+1}x^{\frac{1+n}{n}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                Even longer!
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $-\frac{2}{3}(4-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                In order to do this, we must first make a substitution\ldots
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{$\int(2x)^{50}\mathrm{d}x$}
            \begin{shortsolution}
                $\frac{1}{102}(2x-1)^{51}+C$
            \end{shortsolution}
            \begin{longsolution}
                A very long solution| much longer than the shorter solution
            \end{longsolution}
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

% close solution files
\Closesolutionfile{shortsolutions}
\Closesolutionfile{longsolutions}


\clearpage
\section{SHORT answers}
% renew the SHORT solution environment so that it hyperlinks back to 
% the question
\renewenvironment{shortSoln}[1]{%
         % add some glue
         \vskip .5cm plus 2cm minus 0.1cm%
         {\bfseries \hyperlink{question:#1}{#1.}}%
}%
{%
}%
% input the file if it exists
\IfFileExists{shortsolutions.tex}{\input{shortsolutions.tex}}{}

\clearpage
\section{LONG answers}
% renew the LONG solution environment so that it hyperlinks back to 
% the question
\renewenvironment{longSoln}[1]{%
         % add some glue
         \vskip .5cm plus 2cm minus 0.1cm%
         {\bfseries \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\hyperlink{question:#1}{#1.}}%
}%
{%
}%
% input the file if it exists
\IfFileExists{longsolutions.tex}{\input{longsolutions.tex}}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to change here `\newcounter{question}[subsection]`

Comment: Already tried that, nothing ;)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\newcounter{question}[subsubsection]`?

Comment: @Werner, this was my suggestion. I wrote *to change*. But I don't know if the OP tried it.

Comment: I did try that =)

Comment: your mwe isn't very minimal. please shorten it and also include it in your question to make it easier for people to help you. I don't think many people would want to click through three links and browse through 200 lines of code to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: Comparing with my document of close to 10 000 lines, a mwe of around 200 lines IS minimal. An example working in a sterile enviroment is of no use, if it fails to be compatible with other packages and system. 

For your amusement I did try to narrow it down a notch =)