# How to use package 'answers' with one's own solution environment?

Tags: environments, answers

I would like to use the `answers` package to create exercises and answers
(printed in different parts of the document). The exercises should refer to the
solutions with a margin note (via `marginnote`) and the other way around. The
MWE below already works quite well but I couldn't figure out how to define my
own solutions environment (see 'FAILS'). It should be like the exercise
environment, just with label 'Solution' instead of 'Exercise'.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=0.5em,
  spacebelow=0.5em,
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  headpunct={},
  bodyfont=\normalfont%
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{exercise}
% \declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle, sibling=exercise]{solution}% => FAILS

\Newassociation{solution}{sol}{solutions}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{solutions}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 1}
\end{Filesave}

\begin{exercise}[Header 1]\label{exlabel1}\marginnote{Sol.\ p.~\pageref{sollabel1}}\par\noindent
  First exercise
  \begin{solution}[Header 1]\label{sollabel1}\marginnote{Ex.\ p.~\pageref{exlabel1}}\par\noindent
    First solution.
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\clearpage
\section{Section 2}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 2}
\end{Filesave}

\begin{exercise}[Header 2]\label{exlabel2}\marginnote{Sol.\ p.~\pageref{sollabel2}}\par\noindent
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Part 1
  \item Part 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{solution}[Header 2]\label{sollabel2}\marginnote{Ex.\ p.~\pageref{exlabel2}}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Solution Part 1
    \item Solution Part 2
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\Closesolutionfile{solutions}

\clearpage

\input{solutions}

\end{document}
```

The final goal would be to not having to set the labels and margin notes
manually. One idea is to manually define the exercise and solution environments
and to pass the same 'base label' to each of them as an argument. These two
environments then create a label for the exercise and one for its solution
and refer to each other. I tried that in a different post (see
[Page number hyperlinks (exercises to solutions: fail; solutions to exercises: ok)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377328/page-number-hyperlinks-exercises-to-solutions-fail-solutions-to-exercises-ok))
but wasn't too successful yet.

**Update**

Here is how far I got with the ideas on [Adding another answer hyperlinked to the question itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/adding-another-answer-hyperlinked-to-the-question-itself)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{counter}
\numberwithin{counter}{section}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][]{\refstepcounter{counter}\par% #1 = header; #2 = label
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \labelsep 0pt
  \def\mysollabel{#2}
  \preto\mysollabel{sol:}
  \def\myexlabel{#2}
  \preto\myexlabel{ex:}
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries Exercise~\thecounter\ #1]\label{\myexlabel}% this '\label' correctly refers to the exercise
  \marginnote{Solution p.~\pageref{\mysollabel}}%
  \ignorespaces%
}{%
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\Opensolutionfile{solutions}
\Newassociation{solution}{Soln}{solutions}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 1}
\end{Filesave}

\begin{exercise}[Header 1]{ex:1:label}
  First exercise
  \begin{solution}[Header 1]{ex:1:label}
    First solution.
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\clearpage
\section{Section 2}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 2}
\end{Filesave}

\begin{exercise}[Header 2]{ex:2:label}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Part 1
  \item Part 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{solution}[Header 2]{ex:2:label}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Solution Part 1
    \item Solution Part 2
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\Closesolutionfile{solutions}

% Renew the solution environment so that it hyperlinks back to the exercise
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{Soln}[2][]{\par% #1 = header; #2 = label
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \labelsep 0pt
  \def\myexlabel{#2}
  \preto\myexlabel{ex:}
  \def\mysollabel{#2}
  \preto\mysollabel{sol:}
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries Solution~\ref{\myexlabel}\ #1]\hypertarget{\mysollabel}{}%
  \marginnote{\hyperlink{\myexlabel}{Exercise p.~\pageref{\myexlabel}}}%
  \ignorespaces%
}%
{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}%
\makeatother

\clearpage
\IfFileExists{solutions.tex}{\input{solutions.tex}}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/adding-another-answer-hyperlinked-to-the-question-itself it contains the mechanics of how to link back and forth between questions and answers

Comment: Hi, thanks. I looked at it and tried to renew the solution environment (and work with hyperlinks)... see the Update. I'm far from being an expert in LaTeX, so not sure how to continue from the here. I see the trick with renewing the solution environment, but I need to somehow pass a second argument to it (the 'header'). Also, there is some still some major flaw as labels don't show up in the margin notes.

Comment: Not using the `answers` package, but: the `crossref` example here https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/tree/master/examples does exactly that: crossreferencing solutions (and exercises) in the margin.

Comment: Thanks. I copied all files from 'code' to the current working directory, but still obtain `./xsim.interface.code.tex:51: Undefined control sequence. l.51 \NewExpandableDocumentCommand \numberofusedexercises {}`. Out of curiosity, will `xsim` be in texlive at some point?

Comment: Hey there Marius,

I'm having the same problem.  I imagine it's because I'm running this on Debian Stretch and I don't have a recent enough LaTeX engine.  Can you tell me what platform you're seeing this on?

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release: 9.0
Codename: stretch

Cheers,

Comment: Hi, I saw it under Mac OS X 10.12.6 (with both TeXLive 2016 and 2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my **Update** I tried to improve the code. I realized that `Soln` needs to have three arguments and I made them all formal/required arguments so that `answers` can work with them (this part originally failed). I didn't need to use `hyperlink` specifically (the links turned out correctly). I'll convert this MWE into the original document and see whether everything still works (I'll report back if not). Feel free to comment on possible improvements of the code.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{counter}
\numberwithin{counter}{section}

\newenvironment{exercise}[2]{\refstepcounter{counter}\par% #1 = header; #2 = label
  \trivlist
  \labelsep 0pt
  \def\mysollabel{#2}
  \preto\mysollabel{sol:}
  \def\myexlabel{#2}
  \preto\myexlabel{ex:}
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries Exercise~\thecounter~(#1)]\label{\myexlabel}% this '\label' refers to the exercise
  \marginnote{Solution~p.~\pageref{\mysollabel}}%
  \ignorespaces%
}{%
  \endtrivlist
}

\Opensolutionfile{solutions}
\Newassociation{solution}{Soln}{solutions}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises Section 1}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 1}
\end{Filesave}

\newcommand*{\headerOne}{Header 1}
\begin{exercise}{\headerOne}{ex:1:label}\\
  First exercise
  \begin{solution}{\headerOne}{ex:1:label}\\
    First solution.
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\clearpage
\section{Exercises Section 2}
\begin{Filesave}{solutions}
  \clearpage
  \section{Solutions Section 2}
\end{Filesave}

\newcommand*{\headerTwo}{Header 2}
\begin{exercise}{\headerTwo}{ex:2:label}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Part 1
  \item Part 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{solution}{\headerTwo}{ex:2:label}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Solution Part 1
    \item Solution Part 2
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\Closesolutionfile{solutions}

\renewenvironment{Soln}[3]{% #1 = label (from 'answers'; #2 = header; #3 = label
  \pushQED{\qed}
  \trivlist
  \labelsep 0pt
  \def\myexlabel{#3}
  \preto\myexlabel{ex:}
  \def\mysollabel{#3}
  \preto\mysollabel{sol:}
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries Solution~#1~(#2)]\label{\mysollabel}%
    \marginnote{Exercise~p.~\pageref{\myexlabel}}%
    \ignorespaces%
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist
}

\clearpage
\IfFileExists{solutions.tex}{\input{solutions.tex}}{}

\end{document}
```