# How to hyperlink item when enumerating, i.e. the text in the links are not manually encoded

Tags: hyperref, enumerate

How do you hyperlink items without manually encoding the text of the hyperlink?

Suppose I want to number some items

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blah
\item blah blah
\item blah blah blah
```

and I want each number to be a hyperlink. Say Item 1, Item 2, Item 3.

I tried

```
\begin{enumerate}[\hyperlink{Item 1}{Item 1}]
```

like I would normally do when not hyperlinking; it didn't work.

EDIT: What I really want to do is to label some questions with Q.1, Q.2, Q.3, ...
and have these hyperlinked to answers A.1, A.2, A.3, ..., respectively. Is there a way for the items to be hyperlinked automatically and still be itemized automatically? I.e. the closer I got to the is to get every item hyperlinked but every item has the same number, e.g. Q.1, Q.1, ...

Comment: Hyperlinks point somewhere. Where do you want these hyperlinks to point to? If you're just talking about reformatting the way the enumeration is listed, then both the [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (the latter is preferred) will help. Please clarify.

Comment: For instance I want to make a list of questions which are linked to some answers. Do I need to encode each link in the list manually? or is there some sleek way to do it. just as we can use \begin{enumerate}[1] to itemize the list with numbers.

Comment: And thank you @Werner by the way for editing my lousy question. I don't know how to do the gray-box thing.

Comment: have a look at [best-way-to-part-answers-from-solutions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45415/best-way-to-part-answers-from-solutions) it seems very relevant

Comment: @latexnoob: You simply indent code blocks by four spaces. You can also mark it and press CTRL+K. Inline code is marked using backticks: `\`code\``

Answer (score 3):

You wrote in a later comment: "For instance I want to make a list of questions which are linked to some answers".  This can be achieved with the usual `\label`-`\ref` device and the optional argument to `\item`.

In the example below the answers are in the default `enumerate` environment.  However, questions use the references to the answers instead of the default labels.  Hyperref makes them clickable (try this!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Questions
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\ref{item:earth}.] What is the diameter of Earth?
\item[\ref{item:dwarfs}.] How many dwarfs were there in
  \emph{Sleeping Beauty?}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

Answers
\begin{enumerate}
\item 6400\,km\label{item:earth}
\item Seven\label{item:dwarfs}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[For extra credit: find all the errors in the answers]

Comment: This is quite a manual (and delicate) approach- the `answers` package provides a much more robust method- see the linked question above

Comment: @cmhughes Surely.  For serious work one should use a specialized package.  For one-time quick hack it is easier to write it than to find a package and learn how to use it.