# Setting up a Multiple Choice Answer Key

Tags: answers

I had a question about setting up a LaTeX document. I'm not sure if it is proper to post such a question here, but I figured that many people here have experience with the system and might be able to help.

I've been asked to write a list of questions with multiple choice answers. The people who will be using it don't know much about TeX, so I need to try to make the code as robust as possible. I've written a command to automatically produce the multiple choice options: the command

```
\mc{2}{3}{5}{7}{11}
```

roughly outputs

```
(A) 2  (B) 3  (C) 5  (D) 7  (E) 11
```

What I'd like to do is add in a sixth argument that will take the answer to the question and then automatically append it to a list at the end of the document, essentially creating an answer key. The problem is that it's not clear to me how to call the sixth argument of every `\mc` command into an `\enumerate` environment at the end of the document.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or suggestions anyone may have regarding this project.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the `exam` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could adapt the solution from [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time) for this purpose:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\AnswersList{}
\newcommand\AddAnswer[1]{\edef\AnswersList{\AnswersList#1\endgraf}}

\newcommand*{\mc}[6]{%
    % code to display the multiple choice for #1...#5
    \AddAnswer{#6,}%
}%

\begin{document}

\mc{2}{3}{5}{7}{11}{3}
\mc{2}{3}{5}{7}{11}{5}


The list of answers are:

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\foreach \answer in \AnswersList {%
    \item \answer
}%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a possible solution using the features provided by the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) document class and the [`answers`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/answers) package:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}

\newtheorem{ex}{}{}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{}
\renewcommand\questionshook{\leftmargin0pt}
\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\section{Problems}

\begin{ex}
\begin{questions}
\question
One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not
the same. Which one is different?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice John
\choice Paul
\choice George
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{oneparchoices}
\begin{sol}
Socrates
\end{sol}
\end{questions}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
\begin{questions}
\stepcounter{question}
\question
One of these numbers is perfect.

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $2$
\choice $28$
\choice $5$
\choice $3$
\choice $7$
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\begin{sol}
$7$
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know the answer for 2 is not 7 (just in case).

Comment: However, it's the successor of one :)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408231