# How to define environments for questions and answers

Tags: environments, lists, exam

I wish to do a simple question and answer sheet for my students. I'd like to have something like this:

```
\section{Differential Equations}

    \begin{questions}

         \begin{question}
              ... Question here ...
         \end{question}

         \begin{answer}
              ... Answer here ...
         \end{answer}

    \end{questions}
```

I wish to have the environment QUESTIONS to have counters like enumerate. That is, each `\begin{question} ... \end{question}` should behave just like `\item` in

```
\begin{question} 
\item 
\end{question}
```

The `\begin{question} ... \end{question}` environment should take "normal" LaTeX commands.

If possible, I'd wish to have deferred printing to print the answers at the end of the document.

I first tried this

```
\makeatletter
\newtoks\answerscollect
\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\def\thequestion{{\bfseries{Question \arabic{question}. }}\\}

\def\answer#1{%
\protected@edef\answertmp{%
\the\answerscollect\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\noindent\thequestion#1\par}%
\par\answerscollect=\expandafter{\answertmp}}
\def\printanswers{\the\answerscollect\answerscollect={}}
\def\initbox{\answerscollect={\par\noindent Answers:\par}}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{\stepcounter{question}\par\noindent\thequestion#1}
\makeatother
```

but it's not behaving the way I'd love the results to be ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Have you looked at the exam package?
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam
I guess the package `answers` too 
http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/answers/answers.pdf

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I have tried a number of existing packages. They are cool, but do not actually give me the flexibility to do what I want!

Comment: I do not see anything in your question, making the `answers` package not valid. Please state what this package is missing =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, I've looked at them and they are awkward to use. No lack of flexibility, mind you. But then again, I really don't see a simple(r) way to express the rather complex documents to be created... unless you leave the cozy LaTeX world and build a database with questions and answers, and splice the exam together from the result of a query.

Comment: @vonbrand Have you played around with this, for instance: ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf? While, I realise that, you may have specific needs to address, this question is too general to get a good answer (please note that, I am NOT saying the question is bad!). Please help us arrive at a precise question that you'd like to answer. For instance, start with a base code and tell us, what it is lacking. We might work on it one by one and at the end you'd have your derired code. :)

Comment: have you seen [Best way to part answers from solutions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45415) and [Adding another answer hyperlinked to the question itself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45670)

Comment: I am after simplicity and flexibility. Packages like `answer` do provide solutions, but they are an overkill for the simple task that I want to do. Moreover, it's pretty difficult to tweak them ... I've defined new environments viz.
`\newenvironment{questions}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{question}{\item}{}
\newenvironment{answer}{\item}{}`
I wish to go further and defer printing the answers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple use of  `exam` package :

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\printanswers
\begin{document}

\section{Differential Equations}
\begin{questions}
\question ... Short question here ... \answerline[Short answer]
\question ... Question here ... 

\begin{solution}[.2in]
... Answer here ... 
\end{solution}

\question Long descriptive question about everything

\begin{solutionorlines}[2in]
Long descriptive answer is a long descriptive answer that is a long descriptive answer that is along descriptive answer that is along descriptive answer that is along descriptive answer that is a lie.
\end{solutionorlines}

\question Draw an arrow showing north direction.

\begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
$\uparrow$
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{questions}

\ifprintanswers
Stuff to appear only when answers \textbf{are} being printed.
\else
Stuff to appear only when answers \textbf{are not} being printed.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Commenting and uncommenting `\printanswers` yields in one of two following:

1)

[image: Only questions]

2)

[image: Questions with answers]

I don't see any lack of functionality compared to your example.

Comment: At my department, we took exam.cls as a foundation for our own examination class, so that the cover page would always look the same, and it works very well. It is very flexible.