# Any advanced example of layout designing with ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv, book-design

I'm looking for an advanced example of layout designing with ConTeXt? I've checked reference manual and few another docs from contextgarden, but they show only simple, elementary things. I'm interested in layouts that contains a lot of graphics and doesn't look like mathematical textbooks. And I need to know how to make them efficiently with ConTeXt.

Seeing complete code of something that looks like magazine or cookbook would be great help in learning.

For example, how to obtain master-page mechanism (applying of defined layouts to selected pages or selected parts of content) with ConTeXt?

Or another, but similar question, I can change font like this:

```
\starttypescript [myface1]
\definetypeface [myface1] [rm] [serif] [bob] [default]
\definetypeface [myface1] [ss] [sans] [alice] [default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [myface2]
\definetypeface [myface2] [rm] [serif] [bob2] [default]
\definetypeface [myface2] [ss] [sans] [alice2] [default]
\stoptypescript

{\switchtobodyfont[myface1,12pt]
bla bla
...bla}

{\switchtobodyfont[myface2,10pt]
even more bla bla...
...bla}
```

But can I select pages (odd, even, 11-26, or another combination) and make them to use defined typescript/typeface?

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35036/586?

Comment: It is not possible to automatically change font on a specific page in TeX. TeX does paragraph breaking first and page breaking next. Fonts need to be known at the time of paragraph breaking, and hence cannot be reset after page breaking is done. It be possible to obtain a solution using LuaTeX or a multi-pass mechanism, but AFAIK, it is not possible out of the box in TeX.

Comment: BTW, it is better to ask short specific questions rather than a generic question like. You are also using _layout_ and _typeface_ interchangeably, while they refer to different things in ConTeXt.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., Yes I've seen this topic.

Comment: @Aditya, No, I do not use layout and typeface interchangeably. Perhaps you should read my post again. I have a lot of specific questions, seriously a lot. And I know that would be much better for me (perhaps for other ConTeXt beginners too) to see one really advanced and complicated book/magazine coded in ConTeXt than asking one small question by another. BTW, this looks like short specific question: how to obtain master-page mechanism with ConTeXt without pain? Don't be shy, feel free to answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is being asked here, we have no idea of what you might consider “advanced” or “complicated”. What exactly do you mean by “master-page” mechanism? Have a look at [`\definelayout`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definelayout) or [makeups](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup). Or have a look at the [manual sources](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/) for some existing code.

Comment: **[master pages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-7105a.html)** explained, but it is very common, basic therm in designing books. I thought it is obvious. By advanced, complicated layouts I mean layouts of newspapers or cookbooks or something that is not as simple as science journal or crime novel. I hope, that you've been in bookstore and you've seen how books can look like. Some of them look simple, some of them look complicated (I'm talking about form, not about content). I'm not able to explain this in different way, it is elementary.

Comment: To expand on what @Marco suggested, probably the most complex document available is the [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) (source at http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/metafun/). It boasts tons of graphics and doesn’t resemble math papers at all. Also I strongly recommend the [Layouts manual](http://www.h2o-books.com/node/12). Though for weird requirements like “selecting a page and assigning it a typeface” (‽) you may be better off using a drawing program.

Comment: @phg, Layouts in ConTeXt looks very promising, unfortunately isn't free.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of context manuals?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for examples with a lot of graphical elements, so you probably want to take a look at

**[The ConTeXt manuals](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Manuals)**

This page on the ConTeXt Garden wiki accumulates all the manuals which exist for ConTeXt.  What is more important is that the sources for all the manuals can be accessed online:  http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/  This probably comes closest to what you are looking for.  In principle you could copy these layouts and plug in your own content.