# Complex Page Layout in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, grid-typesetting

I'm a complete beginner at LaTeX, and I'm trying to typeset a complex layout.
How should I go about building a page like the one shown below.
[image: example layout]

**Edit**
I was able to replicate the layout using `minipages` with the `multicols` package.
The images were embedded using the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a bit more information about the logical structure of this page. Does it flow from the all-text block to the green block and from there to the red and blue blocks, or do the red and blue blocks follow the all-text block (and then on to the green, orange, and navy blocks? How big is the overall page? Are the upper two blocks supposed to be squares or rectangles?

Comment: You can use `minipage`s with fixed height.

Comment: It seems clear that Yainnis Lazarides knows how to do this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35162/

Comment: Also check out tabular, \framebox, \parbox, \usepackage{graphics}, \resizebox and \includegraphics.  Truth is, what TeX does is pack boxes inside other boxes.  Every letter is a box.  Every word, line of text, paragraph and page is a box.

Comment: Have you had a look at the flowfram package?