# Different proofs in amsmath with different QED symbol?

Tags: amsmath

I'm trying to expand the amsmath package to get two different proof environments:

- `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}` and
- `\begin{proof*} ... \end{proof*}`

so `proof*` should act exactly like proof except of the QED Symbol.
`proof` should provide be a blacksquare while `proof*` provides the normal square.

I found

```
\let\proof*\proof
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

in some questions but this changes every QED symbol. Any advice?

Comment: *Not an answer/advice*: `\let\proof*\proof` is wrong, it will *let* `\proof` be `*` and then *use* `\proof` which is equal to `*`. In case you want to copy something like that (for some reason), with `etoolbox` you can `\cslet{proof*}\proof`.

Comment: I think there's a seperate command for this. Consider `thmtools`, there's a good example that I found in the http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35093/44160 (Show off your `LaTeX` skills), which uses `gridenv` for QED-symbols but other theorems without it.

Comment: ok i used  
` \usepackage{etoolbox}
\cslet{proof*}\proof
\renewenvironment{proof*}{{\qedsymbol}}{$\blacksquare$} `  
but now proof* doesn't provide a linebreak behind the \blacksquare. so it doesn't act like proof :(

Comment: Add in a `\par` after the last dollar sign? :D

Comment: \cslet{proof*}\proof doesn't work at all :/

Comment: Another option is to hook your environment (automatic version, this is the manual version), by basically renewing `\qedsymbol` several times through your document, e.g.: `\let\bs{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}}\relax\let\ns{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\rule[1pt]{5pt}{5pt}}\relax` or something, I'm not sure what the sign is for the regular QED symbol.

Comment: @Frank don't attempt to `\let` your way out of defining `proof*`, it is much better to just define the `proof*` env.

Comment: @ Frank I did not meant you to do so, just explained that it didn't do what you expected (although I don't see a reason to do so, as seen in the answers, it's not needed). @1010011010 What is that? `\let\bs{…` wil let `\bs` to be exactly `{`. `\let` command only picks the first two tokens, no a group `{…}`

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for spotting the mistake. I suppose `\newcommand` will do the trick then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a direct solution just using the AMS packages.  We set up a new environment `myproof`, which is `proof` but containing a redefinition of the `\qedsymbol`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand*{\myproofname}{My proof}
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\myproofname]{\begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}}{\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  Usual proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{myproof}
  New proof style.
\end{myproof}

\begin{proof}[Short]
  Standard proof
  \begin{equation*}
    a = b. \qedhere
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\begin{myproof}[Short new style]
  New proof style
  \begin{equation*}
    a = b. \qedhere
  \end{equation*}
\end{myproof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I also tend to use `ntheorem` as Bernard show. Just wanted to add how I'd do this with `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{proof*}[1][\proofname]{
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\rule{3mm}{3mm}}
  \begin{proof}[#1]}{\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  sfadf
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of ...]
  sfadf
\end{proof}


\begin{proof*}
  asdfsf
\end{proof*}

\begin{proof*}[Proof of ...]
  sfadf
\end{proof*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `etoolbox` or `\ifblank` if you use `\newenvironment{proof*}[1][\proofname]{…}` you just pass `#1` to `\begin{proof}[#1]` and it automatically works.

Comment: @Manuel, your're right, updated

Answer (score 7):

This is quite easy with the `ntheorem` package. Moreover, it manages correctly the placement of end-of-proof symbols when the proof ends in a displayed equation. I added the `cleveref` package to show how it manages reference types (if the cited theorem were to become a proposition, for instance, its reference would be changed accordingly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{blackproof}{Proof}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is an important theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of \cref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{blackproof}[of \cref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{blackproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You add a lot of packages to most of your answers, although it's not *wrong*, I think it's not desired. Since you remove some clarity on the answer, and new users may not know which package does what and just copy all of them to their “never ending template”.

Comment: @Manuel: Sorry, I simply slighly modified an old file, and forgot to remove fonts loading. I'll delete it at once ( but leave the image as is, I think it's unimportant).

Comment: No need to “sorry”, I was just pointing that out because it was my opinion. I like your `fourier`ised answers, by the way :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution with `thmtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt plus 6pt,
  spacebelow=6pt plus 6pt,
  headfont=\itshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace={ },
  qed=\protect\thisproofqed,
]{proof}

\declaretheorem[
  name=\protect\thisproofname,
  style=proof,
  numbered=no,
]{gproof}

\newcommand\thisproofname{}
\newcommand\thisproofqed{}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
  {\renewcommand\thisproofname{#1}%
   \renewcommand\thisproofqed{$\blacksquare$}%
   \gproof}
  {\endgproof}

\newenvironment{proof*}[1][\proofname]
  {\renewcommand\thisproofname{#1}%
   \renewcommand\thisproofqed{\openbox}%
   \gproof}
  {\endgproof}


\begin{document}

A starred proof follows.

\begin{proof*}
Something.
\end{proof*}

An unstarred proof follows.

\begin{proof}
Something.
\end{proof}

A starred proof follows.

\begin{proof*}
Something.
\end{proof*}

Let's see if we can nest them.

\begin{proof*}
Something depending on a lemma.
\begin{proof}[Proof of the lemma]
Wow!
\end{proof}
The end.
\end{proof*}

\end{document}
```

The advantage is of *not* using `ntheorem` and so being able to use `\qedhere` as provided by `amsthm`.

[image]