# Two different `proof' environments with different headings and qed symbols

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, proof-package

In my book, I am using two different `proof` environments. The original `proof` environment in the AMS packages has been modified to the following:

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    %   \vspace{-\topsep}% remove the space after the theorem
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont
    \topsep0pt \partopsep0pt % no space before
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
    \scshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
}{%
    \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
    \addvspace{3ex} % some space after
}
\makeatother
```

This is my primary `proof` environment and I do not want to change anything about this. The secondary `proof` environment is defined simply via

```
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{prf}{Proof}
```

Here everything is fine, except I just want to add `\square` as the `qedsymbol` at the end (just like any proof). The answer in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192096/different-proofs-in-amsmath-with-different-qed-symbol) is making both the proof-headings similar which I do not want.

Comment: Please attach the image of  `qed` that you want.

Comment: In the primary `proof` environment, I have (and want) `\blacksquare` as the `\qedsymbol`. In the secondary `prf` environment, I need `\square` as the `\qedsymbol`.

Comment: The theorem and proof environments are quite different, and theorems aren't set up to have an ending symbol.  This answer to a previous question provides that ability: [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)