# Redefining an environment and summary box using grid and gridleno

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, typography

This question is inspired by Gonzalo's great answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday/35093#35093) concerning his creation of `gridleno.sty` to enhance the functionality of [`grid.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grid).

Ultimately I have two seemingly simple questions (please let me know if I should post the questions separately if needed), but I have not been able achieve my desired effect despite some fiddling around with parameters and the like.

**(1):** How could the `summary` box/environment be modified to have `10pt` indentation *uniformly* instead of it just being indented on both sides as it currently is (I think it looks weird to have zero indentation on top and bottom, like the box is rather crammed):

[image]

Relevant snippet:

```
% environment for a summary
\newenvironment{summary}
  {\grcmpage{\linewidth}{summarybg}
   \hfil{\color{summaryhead}\bfseries\summaryname}\hfil\par%
     \parshape 1 10pt \dimexpr\linewidth-20pt\relax\itshape}
  {\par\endgrcmpage\par\prevdepth\tpd}
```

**(2):** This question is less important because I know a "workaround," but it doesn't seem very efficient. I really like the `exercises` environment in `gridleno.sty`:

[image]

Relevant snippet:

```
% environment for exercises: facy title and redefines enumerate as exenumerate
% to remove labels indentation
\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\section*{\Hrulefill\quad%
    {\bfseries\exercisesname}\quad\Hrulefill}%
  \let\enumerate\exenumerate\let\endenumerate\endexenumerate}
  {}
```

---

I would like to use this environment but have flexibility with different headings. For example, I would also like to have a `solutions` environment that functioned exactly as the `exercises` environment here, and I can do this by simply creating the new environment in `gridleno.sty` but the most efficient approach here, it seems, would be something along the lines of having an optional argument for the `exercises` environment, much as the AMS `proof` environment has an optional argument such as `\begin{proof}[Solution]...\end{proof}`.

If possible, I'd like to have `\begin{exercises}[<heading>]...\end{exercises}` to where I could use "Solutions" as one heading or something completely different. This would be much nicer, I think, than simply duplicating code almost but changing one word here and one word there (but I don't know how to modify the `exercise` environment to do this).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Untested as you don't provide working code, but for the second question

```
\newenvironment{exercises}[1][Exercises]
  {\section*{\Hrulefill\quad%
    {\bfseries #1}\quad\Hrulefill}%
  \let\enumerate\exenumerate\let\endenumerate\endexenumerate}
  {}
```

would let you say

```
\begin{exercises}
  \item items with Exercises as title
\end{exercises}
```

or

```
\begin{exercises}[Solutions]
  \item items with Solutions as title
\end{exercises}
```

Probably. Hard to know without knowing how all the bits there are defined. Might not work at all. But, heck, if you wanted *working* code, you'd have provided a Minimum Working Example so I could test it.

Comment: I don't see any reason to be edgy here--I can provide a MWE if desired, but I refrained from doing so in order to prevent a rather long post from being much longer. I left Gonzalo a comment from an earlier interaction with him today in case he wanted to address this (originally was going to ask him in a comment, but this seemed enough to warrant a new question). Regardless, I can confirm that your solution for my second question checks out. Thank you.