# Using list with tagstoc package

Tags: lists, tags

I'm using the package described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37972/228451) to build a tag based article.

I have a list of csv strings which is used to build a table and I would like to use the first instance of the csv string as a tag too.

```
\listadd\aka{DVM , Distillation with value matching, RL}
\listadd\aka{RL , Reinforcement Learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{MARL , Multi agent reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{RND , random network distillation, Novelty RL }
\listadd\aka{DRL , Deep reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{MADRL , Multi agent Deep reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{NLP , Natural language processing, NLP}
\listadd\aka{EM ,Emergent communication, EM}
\listadd\aka{LtT , Learning to teach , RL}
\listadd\aka{AA, Action advising , LtT }
\listadd\aka{TB, teacher budget, LtT }
\listadd\aka{CA, Continuous Actions, RL }
\listadd\aka{DA, Discrete Actions, RL}
\listadd\aka{NN, Noisy Nets , General }
\listadd\aka{SiA , Student initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{JiA , Joint initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{TiA , Teacher initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{DDS , Dynamic difficulty scaling , Flow}
\listadd\aka{BB , Believable bots , Flow}
\listadd\aka{ToF , Theory of flow , Flow}
\listadd\aka{GBL , Game-based learning , Flow}
\listadd\aka{HRL , Hierarchical reinforcement learning , RL}



\newcommand{\addtag}[1]{
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \declaretag{\mylist[1]}}

\newcommand*{\addtags}{\forlistloop{\addtag}{\aka}}
```

The commands `addtags` and `addtag` iterate through the list, grab the first csv element (with `\readlist*\mylist{#1}`) and use `declaretag` with it.
When I try to use `addtags` in the document it gives a `LaTex Error: No counter '1' defined` and seems to consider the last tag only.
On the other hand,  if i use `declaretag` as:

```
\declaretag{DVM}
\declaretag{RL}
...
\declaretag{HRL}
```

It works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit 1

I'm editing to answer the request for more information.

So my actual aim is to keep a list (aka) of tags with related description and domain (comma separated values).

This list is used to fill a tabular with:

```
% create row with three elements
\newcommand{\fillrow}[1]{
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[1] & %
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[2] & %
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[3] \\ \hline
}

% fill tabular
\newcommand*{\filltab}{\forlistloop{\fillrow}{\aka}}
```

And i would like it to work with the `tagstoc` package made by [Ryan Reich](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/575/ryan-reich) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37928/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tag-content-in-a-latex-document/37972#37972):

```
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Here's the package file
\begin{filecontents*}{tagstoc.sty}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

% Declare the master TOC.  This will contain:
% * A list of tags
% * A sequence of entries where tags are referenced
% and it will be used multiple times to generate lists of tag usage
\newlistof{tags}{tags}{All tags}
\renewcommand*\cfttagstitlefont{\Large\bfseries}% For example

% Use this in the preamble to make a new tag.
\newcommand*\declaretag[1]{%
 \newlistentry[tags]{tag#1}{tags}{0}%
 \listadd\Tags{#1}%
 \addtocontents{tags}{(#1) }%
}
% This is only true when printing the list of tags
\newif\ifprintingtags
% This makes sure that the list of tags is not printed most of the time...
\addtocontents{tags}{\protect\ifprintingtags}
% ...because it wraps the entire TOC from the preamble
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{tags}{\protect\fi}}

% This is a rather inefficient way to selectively print particular tags.
% Presumably, I should just pop each tag from the list as I go,
% but etoolbox doesn't seem to handle stacks.  Probably I'm missing something.
\newcommand*\deactivatetag[1]{%
 \expandafter\let\csname l@tag#1\endcsname=\@gobbletwo
}
\newcommand*\activatetag[1]{%
 \forlistloop\deactivatetag\Tags
 \expandafter\let\csname l@tag#1\endcsname=\l@section
}

% These are hooks for the user
\providecommand*\currenttag{}
\providecommand*\listoftagstitle{}
% This prints all the references to a particular tag.
% Effectively, it's a partial ToC for that tag.
\newcommand*\dotag[1]{%
 \renewcommand*\currenttag{#1}%
 \begingroup
  \activatetag{#1}%
  \section*{\listoftagstitle}%
  \@input{\jobname.tags}%
 \endgroup
}%
% This prints the snippets, placed (with repeats) beneath their tags.
% It also prints a list of defined tags, more or less as an excuse
% to have \listoftags handle the .tags auxiliary ToC file.
\newcommand*\snippetsbytag{%
 \forlistloop\dotag\Tags
 \activatetag{}
 \printingtagstrue
 \listoftags
}

% This is how to proclaim a snippet, which is what gets tagged.
\newcounter{snippet}
\providecommand*\snippetname{}
\newcommand*\snippettitle{\snippetname}
\newcommand*\snippet[1]{%
 \refstepcounter{snippet}%
 \renewcommand*\snippetname{#1}%
 \noindent{\normalsize\bfseries\snippettitle.}%
}

% In case of no hyperref
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
% This is how you place a tag beneath a snippet.
\newcommand*\placetag[1]{%
 \phantomsection% In case of hyperref
 \addcontentsline{tags}{tag#1}{\snippettitle}%
 (tag~#1)%
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tagstoc}

\renewcommand*\listoftagstitle{Snippets tagged with \currenttag}
% Preferred way to declare tags.  They will be printed in this order.
```

So to add all the tags from the list with a custom command such as the one I tried:

```
\newcommand{\addtag}[1]{
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \declaretag{\mylist[1]}}

\newcommand*{\addtags}{\forlistloop{\addtag}{\aka}}
```

But when I use it the whole thing goes crazy and the last element of the list (HRL) is repeated for 22 times (the elements in the list).

Hope this clarifies thing.

### Edit 2

I'm adding a working document that you can check

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}





\usepackage{filecontents}

% Here's the package file
\begin{filecontents*}{tagstoc.sty}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

% Declare the master TOC.  This will contain:
% * A list of tags
% * A sequence of entries where tags are referenced
% and it will be used multiple times to generate lists of tag usage
\newlistof{tags}{tags}{All tags}
\renewcommand*\cfttagstitlefont{\Large\bfseries}% For example

% Use this in the preamble to make a new tag.
\newcommand*\declaretag[1]{%
 \newlistentry[tags]{tag#1}{tags}{0}%
 \listadd\Tags{#1}%
 \addtocontents{tags}{(#1) }%
}
% This is only true when printing the list of tags
\newif\ifprintingtags
% This makes sure that the list of tags is not printed most of the time...
\addtocontents{tags}{\protect\ifprintingtags}
% ...because it wraps the entire TOC from the preamble
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{tags}{\protect\fi}}

% This is a rather inefficient way to selectively print particular tags.
% Presumably, I should just pop each tag from the list as I go,
% but etoolbox doesn't seem to handle stacks.  Probably I'm missing something.
\newcommand*\deactivatetag[1]{%
 \expandafter\let\csname l@tag#1\endcsname=\@gobbletwo
}
\newcommand*\activatetag[1]{%
 \forlistloop\deactivatetag\Tags
 \expandafter\let\csname l@tag#1\endcsname=\l@section
}

% These are hooks for the user
\providecommand*\currenttag{}
\providecommand*\listoftagstitle{}
% This prints all the references to a particular tag.
% Effectively, it's a partial ToC for that tag.
\newcommand*\dotag[1]{%
 \renewcommand*\currenttag{#1}%
 \begingroup
  \activatetag{#1}%
  \section*{\listoftagstitle}%
  \@input{\jobname.tags}%
 \endgroup
}%
% This prints the snippets, placed (with repeats) beneath their tags.
% It also prints a list of defined tags, more or less as an excuse
% to have \listoftags handle the .tags auxiliary ToC file.
\newcommand*\snippetsbytag{%
 \forlistloop\dotag\Tags
 \activatetag{}
 \printingtagstrue
 \listoftags
}

% This is how to proclaim a snippet, which is what gets tagged.
\newcounter{snippet}
\providecommand*\snippetname{}
\newcommand*\snippettitle{\snippetname}
\newcommand*\snippet[1]{%
 \refstepcounter{snippet}%
 \renewcommand*\snippetname{#1}%
 \noindent{\normalsize\bfseries\snippettitle.}%
}

% In case of no hyperref
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
% This is how you place a tag beneath a snippet.
\newcommand*\placetag[1]{%
 \phantomsection% In case of hyperref
 \addcontentsline{tags}{tag#1}{\snippettitle}%
 (tag~#1)%
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tagstoc}

\renewcommand*\listoftagstitle{Snippets tagged with \currenttag}
% Preferred way to declare tags.  They will be printed in this order.





\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listofitems}

% create row with three elements
\newcommand{\fillrow}[1]{
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[1] & %
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[2] & %
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \mylist[3] \\ \hline
}

% fill tabular
\newcommand*{\filltab}{\forlistloop{\fillrow}{\aka}}




\listadd\aka{DVM , Distillation with value matching, RL}
\listadd\aka{RL , Reinforcement Learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{MARL , Multi agent reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{RND , random network distillation, Novelty RL }
\listadd\aka{DRL , Deep reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{MADRL , Multi agent Deep reinforcement learning, RL }
\listadd\aka{NLP , Natural language processing, NLP}
\listadd\aka{EM ,Emergent communication, EM}
\listadd\aka{LtT , Learning to teach , RL}
\listadd\aka{AA, Action advising , LtT }
\listadd\aka{TB, teacher budget, LtT }
\listadd\aka{CA, Continuous Actions, RL }
\listadd\aka{DA, Discrete Actions, RL}
\listadd\aka{NN, Noisy Nets , General }
\listadd\aka{SiA , Student initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{JiA , Joint initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{TiA , Teacher initiated approach , LtT }
\listadd\aka{DDS , Dynamic difficulty scaling , Flow}
\listadd\aka{BB , Believable bots , Flow}
\listadd\aka{ToF , Theory of flow , Flow}
\listadd\aka{GBL , Game-based learning , Flow}
\listadd\aka{HRL , Hierarchical reinforcement learning , RL}



\newcommand{\addtag}[1]{
\readlist*\mylist{#1} \declaretag{\mylist[1]}}

\newcommand*{\addtags}{\forlistloop{\addtag}{\aka}}




\begin{document}
\addtags




 \snippetsbytag
 \newpage
 

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Aka} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Field} \\ \hline
\filltab
\end{tabular}
\caption{List of acrimonious with corresponding description and field}
\label{tab:akas}
\end{table} 

 \newpage


\snippet{TMp1}
\placetag{SiA}\placetag{NN}\placetag{TiA }

Something

\snippet{TMp2}
\placetag{MADRL}\placetag{HRL}\placetag{TiA }

Something else



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! The code is not really documented and it's probably better to explain what's your aim.

Comment: Please give a *complete* document such that we can reproduce the problem. If I start the document with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{listofitems}\usepackage{tagstoc}`, add your code, and finish with `\begin{document}\addtags\end{document}`, I don't get any error.

Comment: I edited the post to provide the info you asked for